# Shell script to display output and store at same time?

Tags: shell, store

When I go and type

```
./script.txt
```

It displays the output in terminal, but if I want to display it on the screen and store it at the same time, how do I do this? Because If I do

```
./script.txt >> example.txt
```

It will only store it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
./script.txt 2>&1 | tee -a example.txt
```

The `2>&1` redirects stderr into the stdout stream. Now both streams come thru the pipe to tee, which dupes a file for output AND also sends a copy of all input to its stdout.

I hope this helps.

P.S. you're not really naming your scripts with `.txt` extension are you? ;-)

Comment: Using cygwin so... just creating notepad files.

Comment: did you mean to say 'redirects `stderr` to `stdout`'

Comment: If you transfer that file to a linux box, you'll have troubles with the \r\n line endings. be sure to use dos2unix once  you get it transfered. Good luck.